# Video Card in a laptop

Tags: memory, video

I have a toshiba satellite series laptop with Intel 4000 HD graphics.with only 16mb left of VRAM.I want to know if buying a new graphic card will increase my VRAM and is it possible to add a new graphic card to my laptop.If possible how?

Comment: There's no plausible way of adding a graphics card to a laptop.

Comment: Your laptop does not have the capability to run a new graphic cards, even if mobile GPUs were sold, which they are not at least not by retailers.

Comment: ".I want to know if buying a new graphic card will increase my VRAM". Yes, since the other parts of the notebook will be replaced too.

Comment: @Rinzwind the whole notebook, actually.

Comment: Note that you can often increase the memory dedicated to VRAM in the BIOS settings. I'm not sure if that is specifically true in your case.

Comment: @Zacharee1 There have been a few laptops that did have replaceable and upgradeable video cards. I had one, a Dell Latitude iirc. Dell used a different card in their "workstation laptop" line ("Precision") and it was possible to use the card that they sold with the Precision in the Latitude. Only a few laptops were capable of this and the selection of video cards  for them was very small. Today these cases are very rare, as the push now is for ever-thinner laptops and the connectors necessary to allow pluggable video cards do add bulk. For the 99.999% case though your comment is correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't upgrade the GPU or CPU(with Integrated graphics) with this Laptop. Generally, thats impossible with Laptops. You are sadly limited to upgrading your RAM or HDD/SSD.

Of course, you could get an External Graphics Card, which would require a dock plus a graphics card, though then the Laptop wont be portable anymore, and its not extremely fast, espiacially when your other Hardware is not accordingly powerful.

So I'd say the best Solution is: Get a new, proper Laptop, and if you just use it at home, get a Desktop PC.

Comment: Something that suits his needs in terms of Performance and Budget,.